# How can i minimize this pl sql update

Tags: plsql

I am new in PL SQL.I want to update a table row values.I want to take the values from php in xml format and update that specific row values.So i write this pl sql function and **it works fine**.
Here is the code:

```
FUNCTION update_payroll_transaction(employeeData NVARCHAR2) RETURN CLOB IS

ret CLOB;
xmlData XMLType;
v_code NUMBER;
v_errm VARCHAR2(500);
num1 number(4,0);
BEGIN
xmlData:=XMLType(employeeData);
UPDATE payrollfile ep SET(
                      SALYR,
                      SALMT,
                      EMPID,
                      DPTID,
                      SALHD,
                      DESCRP,
                      ALAMT,
                      OPID,
                      TRADT) = (SELECT x.SALYR,
                      x.SALMT,
                      x.EMPID,
                      x.DPTID,
                      x.SALHD,
                      x.DESCRP,
                      x.ALAMT,
                      x.OPID,
                      x.TRADT FROM XMLTABLE('/transaction'
                                                PASSING xmlData
                                                COLUMNS  SALYR        NUMBER(4,0)     PATH    'salary_year',
                                                         SALMT        NUMBER(2,0)     PATH    'salary_month',
                                                         EMPID        NUMBER            PATH  'employee_id',
                                                         DPTID         NUMBER          PATH  'department_code',
                                                        SALHD         VARCHAR2(2)     PATH  'salary_head',
                                                        DESCRP         VARCHAR2(50)    PATH  'description',
                                                        ALAMT         FLOAT(126)      PATH  'amount',
                                                        OPID          NUMBER        PATH  'operator_id',
                                                        TRADT         DATE          PATH  'transaction_date') x
                    WHERE ep.EMPID=x.EMPID) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM XMLTABLE('/transaction'
                                                PASSING xmlData
                                                COLUMNS  SALYR        NUMBER(4,0)     PATH    'salary_year',
                                                         SALMT        NUMBER(2,0)     PATH    'salary_month',
                                                         EMPID        NUMBER            PATH  'employee_id',
                                                         DPTID         NUMBER          PATH  'department_code',
                                                        SALHD         VARCHAR2(2)     PATH  'salary_head',
                                                        DESCRP         VARCHAR2(50)    PATH  'description',
                                                        ALAMT         FLOAT(126)      PATH  'amount',
                                                        OPID          NUMBER        PATH  'operator_id',
                                                        TRADT         DATE          PATH  'transaction_date') x WHERE ep.EMPID=x.EMPID);

ret:=to_char(sql%rowcount);
COMMIT;

RETURN '<result><status affectedRow='||ret||'>success</status></result>';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ret);

END update_payroll_transaction;
```

Here is my php code:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, " begin   
                               :result := PAYROLL.update_payroll_transaction('<transaction>
                                        <salary_year>$year</salary_year>
                                        <salary_month>$month</salary_month>
                                        <employee_id>$empID</employee_id>
                                        <department_code>$dptCode</department_code>
                                        <salary_head>$salHD</salary_head>
                                        <description>$description</description>
                                        <amount>$amount</amount>
                                        <operator_id>$optID</operator_id>
                                        <transaction_date>$trDate</transaction_date>
                                      </transaction>');                

                                end;" );    

    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':result',$ru, 5000);   
    $output = oci_execute($stid);
```

I think made the update very long.Is it possible to minimize that code.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd switch to using MERGE; this has the advantage of only referencing the xmltable once, rather than twice as in your update statement:

```
function update_payroll_transaction(employeedata nvarchar2)
return clob
is
  ret clob;
  xmldata xmltype;
  v_code number;
  v_errm varchar2(500);
  num1 number(4,0);
begin
  xmldata:=xmltype(employeedata);

  merge into payrollfile tgt
  using (select salyr,
                salmt,
                empid,
                dptid,
                salhd,
                descrp,
                alamt,
                opid,
                tradt
         from   xmltable('/transaction'
                         passing xmldata
                         columns salyr number(4,0) path 'salary_year',
                                 salmt number(2,0) path 'salary_month',
                                 empid number path 'employee_id',
                                 dptid number path 'department_code',
                                 salhd varchar2(2) path 'salary_head',
                                 descrp varchar2(50) path 'description',
                                 alamt float(126) path 'amount',
                                 opid number path 'operator_id',
                                 tradt date path 'transaction_date')) src
    on (tgt.empid = src.empid)
  when matched then
  update set tgt.salyr = src.salyr,
             tgt.salmt = src.salmt,
             tgt.empid = src.empid,
             tgt.dptid = src.dptid,
             tgt.salhd = src.salhd,
             tgt.descrp = src.descrp,
             tgt.alamt = src.alamt,
             tgt.opid = src.opid,
             tgt.tradt = src.tradt;

  ret:=to_char(sql%rowcount);

  commit;

  dbms_output.put_line(ret);

  return '<result><status affectedRow='||ret||'>success</status></result>';

end update_payroll_transaction;
/
```

Comment: Thanks @Boneist for reply.i try it.But, it seems that the code is not updating the primary key.It is correctly updating rest of the columns except for primary key 'empid' .Is possible to update the primary key using this merge statement? thanks

Comment: Why would you want to update your primary key values?

Comment: Thanks @Boneist for quick reply. actually, i think about situation where one employee transfer from  existing department to new  a department of the same organization.in that case i need to reassign the old primary key instead of another row.Moreover it will help me to learn technique to change primary key.Thanks again.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by primary key, I guess. In the situation you describe, I would expect the empid to remain the same across the organisation, regardless of which dept they worked in. Is that not the case for you?